# How I can host my MVC3 application in .net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-3.5, hosting

I have made my application in ASP.NET MVC 3. The server I use only have 3.5 .net framrwork installed on server.

Please let me know how I can deployed my application in .net 3.5 server. the server I used rackspace hosting and need to host application on the server. I am not own the server. Someone else have own the server and I just give the deployed application on their server.

Please help me on without moving to any other server how I can host my asp.net MVC 3 application. Is it possible to do that thing.

Thanks

Comment: This *was* a real question, and it was answered perfectly. Many people are asking the same question (including myself an hour ago), to find the answer given. I am glad that there was only one answer, but I don't appreciate the disrespect by Xander, @Lex Li, and Kev by using this closure flag.

Comment: I  agree, it was a good question and interesting answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MVC3 requires .NET 4 or greater.  No way around it.

You will have to either upgrade the server to .NET 4 (it can have both 3.5 and 4 installed at the same time) or you will have to downgrade your app to MVC2.  If you are using Razor, that will also mean converting all your views to Webforms views as Razor does not work on .NET 3.5.

Comment: Hello, hosting support tell me that they have done it and setting application root directory as as IIS application from IIS MMC take 15 min to active. I am wait for hour but their is no sign of anything is work.

Comment: I made application in Razor. would you like to tell me If i downgrade to MVC 2 then How I can use razor based view in my application.

Comment: @user1252580 - I said very clearly that you cannot use Razor in .net 3.5